# Fill dat file with empty struct

Tags: c, fwrite

My goal is to create a .dat file which contains 100 empty records. I have started the program with the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

// item structure definition
struct item {
int number; 
char name[10]; 
int quantity;
float cost;
};

// begin main function
int main(){
    int i;
    FILE *cfPtr; 
    cfPtr = fopen("hardware.dat", "w");

    struct item createEmptyRecord = {0, "", "", 0.0};


     for (i=0;i<100;i++){
        // the fwrite function in the stdio.h library 
        // declartion size_t fwrite(const void *ptr, size_t size, size_t nmemb, FILE *stream)
        fwrite (&createEmptyRecord, sizeof (struct item), 1, cfPtr);
    } // end for loop

    fclose(cfPtr);

} // end main function
```

I am getting a .dat output but when I open it to check all of the items are NULL and they have the caracters below. How can I check to see if this is garbage values or I actually initalized 100 structs to blank?

@@                     @@                     @@                     @@                     @@                     @@                     @@                     @@                     @@                     @@

Comment: "" is not zeros, it is the address of a location in memory of a valid string whose first byte is 0. Initializing a character array to that will not fill in the remaining values, and initializing an int will give you some random value.

Comment: @LeeDanielCrocker I believe I got the program to work using:

`struct item createEmptyRecord = {0, "", 0, 0.0};`

My output is as follows: NUL NUL NUL NUL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
struct item createEmptyRecord = {0, "", "", 0.0};
```

Note that here you are passing `""` to initialize an `int` member.  The string literal `""` is not the same as NULL.  If you increase the warning level of your compiler, it should warn you about a `const char*` being converted to a `int`.

The correct way to initialize a struct to all-zero is:

```
struct item createEmptyRecord = {0};
```

Alternatively you can use `memset`:

```
struct item createEmptyRecord;
memset(&createEmptyRecord, 0, sizeof(createEmptyRecord));
```

Comment: Thanks I should've used  

`struct item createEmptyRecord = {0, "", 0, 0.0};`

Due to the fact that I have an int, char, int, and float.

Comment: Well, you might want to check up on Lee Daniel Crocker's claim that initializing an array from empty string doesn't pad the array with zeroes.  I'm pretty sure it does, but I normally use C++ and I might be confusing the two languages.  It's pretty common to see the `memset` approach.  It makes your code simpler.  An alternative is to open the file with truncation as you already do, `fseek` to `100 * sizeof(struct item) - 1` and then write a single 0-byte.  It should pad the beginning of the file with zeros.